# Bootstrap @media isn't work in my case ( React)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
function App(props) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
export default App;
```

app.css

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: chartreuse;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        background-color: crimson;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        background-color: aqua;
    }
}
```

index.html --> see below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Who can help me find an explanation for this issue?It isn't working in my case. Bootstrap is working in my case ( I have added a library for this ). Maybe I don't have some library in my package.json

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-web-app-bootstrap",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-beta"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: "It isn't working" - what isn't working?

Comment: @media - when I change the size of my browser - it doesn't change color of my background - how to fix it?

Comment: If you expect any sensible answers, you need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork and you want to avoid that. Edit your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: In other words, this issue is an HTML/Bootstrap issue. So, you need to post a snippet of the output HTML instead of the react code.

Comment: You can check it above

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich OK, what you need to do when you open the index.html in a browser window is to right-click and choose "inspect". That way you can get and copy the actual contents of the `<div id="root"></div>` because right now, the HTML you posted there, is useless. I doesn't help with debugging.

Comment: Where/when is your custom `app.css` being loaded? Do you know that it has to be loaded **after** the bootstrap.css ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; <--- solving here 
import './App.css'
function App(props) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
export default App;
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation. **For example, add above your code:** Based on comment by @WebDevBooster I changed the order of importing the `.css`:s like this:

Comment: we have to add this line of code (import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';) above this one (import './App.css')

Comment: Please use the "edit" button beneath your answer to edit.

Answer (score 0):

No need to import

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

If you are adding in html like you are added in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

write in app.js

```
const App = () => <div class="demo">App Component</div>
```

write in app.css

```
.demo {
 background-color: red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .demo {
    font-size: 60px;
 }
}
```

Comment: it also working without this lines of code :

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

Comment: what exactly you want to